# Regex to find a pattern repeating at least n times

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm being destroyed by spam and the emails are always different except that they always have similar links like this that repeat several times:

> http://spam.com/hello/world/fk59j356jss5ptttNMdlJ96vmrDsjEeCPDXJf0fBXOi

So I'm trying to put a filter on my server that will scan a slash followed by 30-50 alphanumeric characters, which will then repeat at least 3 times. I wrote the following regular expression but on regex101.com,I keep getting a "timeout" message, probably because there is a better way to write it:

```
/(\/\w{30,50})(.+?\1){3,}/s
```

I tried google but my search terms never returned what I wanted.

**EDIT**

Here's the link so you can see:
https://regex101.com/r/tL9wK7/2
We can identify the spam link with this part that always repeats:

/bcaip86eJR2W5hKmMjFiKVWmKyLjmiMKhkOm0Mjh906

There is always something similar in the spam emails (a slash followed by a series of alphanumeric characters). This link is different in every spam email but it will repeat multiple times in the same email.

So scanning in an email if there is a link with a slash followed by 30-50 alphanumeric characters that appears several times in the same email will reveal that it is spam.

Comment: Can you not search for `spam.com`?

Comment: Maybe just using `/[a-zA-Z0-9]{90,}/` can help? It will match a minimum of 90 alphanumeric characters in a row. What language is it used in? PHP?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could paste the regex101 link that you've tried, so that we know what kind of links you are expecting

Comment: I have put the link. And It cannot be spam.com, this is an example. Of course it will always be different.

Comment: Does the entire link repeat 3 or more times, or just the 30-50 alphanumeric string?

Comment: Good question, the whole links repeat several times, but it's easier to match the last part of the uri with the alphanum since the urls never contain the same amount or parts in the uri

Comment: There's no 3rd occurrence of any string of length 30+ as far as I can tell. If you could actually find 3 that you wish to match, then please. I updated my answer to actually answer your question now, but the input data doesn't fit, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I've improved on your pattern slightly:

```
/(\/\w{30,})(?:.+?\1){3,}?/s
```

Demo link: https://regex101.com/r/aNdURv/1

Key changes:
1. Why stop at 50 characters? Shouldn't matter how long the word is as long as it is at least 30. So I removed "50" from the first group.
2. You don't need to capture each repeat, just to count it towards the total you are aiming for (3 or more), so I added "?:" to the second group.
3. You don't need it to find all matching repeats, meaning it can be lazy and stop as long as it finds at least 3.  So I added "?" to the end.

Comment: Hey there, that was a while ago ;) turns out the server is defective and doesn't even filter emails, so any regex we put there has no effect. However, since you're a new member, that this question is obsolete + especially the fact that I didn't know you could put a question mark for the non-capturing group... That's awesome! I searched for that many times and thought parentheses were always capturing!! thanks friend!

Comment: Thanks!  I did notice it was a couple years old, but this whole post, including learning about regex101, helped me with the exact same need, catching spam with a regex filter on my mail server.  It was worth creating an account to share back what else I learned from my experimentation.  :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
/\/(\w{30,50})(?:.*\1)(?:.*\1)/sg
```

This would solve your question, given example data that filled the criteria. You can see it working by removing the last capture group when used with your regex101 link.

Comment: Hum, not working either, I put the link to regex101 in my question, did not know I could do this, check it out! :)

Comment: That's helpful, but you aren't explaining further what in that chunk of text you wish to match, and the URL supplied in the question isn't in it. To clarify; the regex I posted will match the link you posted.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wanted to be abstract, I'll change my question right now

Comment: Regex is a highly specific science, you can't be inaccurate in the description of what you want to match.

Comment: Your expression is working just like mine, so you have the same problem as me, it's not efficient enough so if the email headers are too big, it will take too much processing time. Try adding an extra (?:.*\1) in your regex and having a longer text in the source, you will hit the timeout on regex101.com. So maybe there is not way of doing this better and it is a costly regex whatever how it's built

Comment: Mine finishes `no match - 127986 steps`. I stated as a comment on your question that your example data doesn't have 3 equal strings over 30 characters long. If you can find some, please post them so I know what to look for. As to the efficiency, this is horrible indeed.

Comment: Hum, the link I posted has 4 times the string copy-pasted on 4 lines, maybe your cache is showing the last version? Anyways, you can just copy-paste a third time the string that is found and it would be the same. But anyways, if you say this is the best performance we can achieve and it's still horrible, well I guess my question doesn't have a perfect answer as I cannot have a better performance than the regex I wrote

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (slight modification of your regex)-

```
(\/\w{30,50})(.*?\1){3,}
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sP7kE8/1)

Comment: Not working for my case, but I posted the regex101.com link in my question now, did not know I could do this! You can have a look :)

Comment: Can you paste the string that you want matched? Its a bit unclear :)

Comment: I added a LOT more info in my question, should make my crappy explanations clearer haha!